# If I use StatefulWidget in StatelessWidget, each StatefulWidget perform like Stateless Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I use Widgets Like this (image). How performed they are?

[image]

Comment: You can observe it yourself with Flutter Dev Tools :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Stateful widget will perform exactly like a Stateless widget unless you mutate the state using `setState` method. The only time UI is rebuilt is when your run the `setState((){})` method inside the Stateful widget.

Sample `setState` example from documentation.

```dart
class Bird extends StatefulWidget {
  const Bird({
    Key? key,
    this.color = const Color(0xFFFFE306),
    this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Color color;
  final Widget? child;

  @override
  State<Bird> createState() => _BirdState();
}

class _BirdState extends State<Bird> {
  double _size = 1.0;

  void grow() {
    setState(() { _size += 0.1; });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: widget.color,
      transform: Matrix4.diagonal3Values(_size, _size, 1.0),
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```

Reference: Stateful Widgets - [LINK](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html)

You can try and learn about Stateful widgets in the above documentation link.